# How to use both Lucene & Solr with Brightcove?

Tags: solr, content-search, lucene

In our project, we are using Brightcove videos, currently brightcove media framework supports only Lucene. But we need to use Solr for the site search, and other functionalities.

How do we enable both the searches? What are all the configurations need to be enabled on the CM & CD servers.

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible, and we use Brightcove with Solr.

Comment: According to https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/setting%20up%20%20maintaining/search%20and%20indexing/indexing/configure%20a%20search%20and%20indexing%20provider it is possible: "When you configure servers you also need to choose a search and indexing provider. You can choose Lucene, Solr or a combination of the two depending on your business purpose and the type of server architecture you want to implement.". I don't know how though.

Comment: If you have access to support portal, ask Sitecore for the Solr file. We got it that way or you can just create one from sitecore_master_index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your Sitecore version, you can have both Solr and Lucene enabled at the same time. Each index configuration will define which provider is used. I have done this in v8.0+

You will need to make sure that both the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` and `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` files are enabled.

Then for your indexes that need to use Lucene, the config should set the type to the Lucene provider:

```
<index id="mediaframework_web_index" 
       type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
  ...
</index>
```

For any indexes that you want to store in Solr, set it to the Solr provider:

```
<index id="sitecore_core_index" 
       type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    ...
</index>
```

Sitecore will create the index objects in code based on the type specified, so both will work.

Caveats:

- You can't store the same index in both Solr and Lucene, the indexes must be unique
- If you have Lucene indexes on the CD servers, you may run into problems with getting the indexes updated. Normally only the CM server would kick off the indexing in a SOLR environment as the indexes are shared across servers. But Lucene are local, so you would have to enable the index updating on the CD servers too, this could cause a *lot* of needless index updates in SOLR. - if you are only using the media framework index for CM data, then it may not be an issue.

It may be better to convert the media framework to use a SOLR index. It should be possible to do this by changing the index config.

Comment: Thanks Richard, so i tried enabling both Lucene & Solr in local, it worked fine, but couldn't find exact documentation on what files need to enabled and disabled for CM & CD.
With another approach, I was able to convert the media framework index to Solr by changing the index config, and it worked fine, all the import & export, video search in content editor working fine.
Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: Richard one more doubt, so when i installed the brightcove media framework connector, it came with Lucene as default. So Is these connectors work with any search provider just by changing the index config? Does it means that they write their search specific code to use ContentSearch library, not any lucene or solr specific?

Comment: @GopikrishnaGujjula, how did you convert media framework index to Solr? I am trying to do this.